# How to catch errors or validate angular material datepicker in the controller?

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

In angular material datepicker, Error messages are shown using ng-Messages but how do I catch those in the controller and validate if no error is there.

```
<form name="myForm">


      <md-datepicker name="dateField" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"
          required md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate"  md-open-on-focus></md-datepicker>

      <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">

        <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
        <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
        <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
        <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>

      </div>

      {{myForm.dateField.$error}}
    </form>
<button ng-click="check(myForm.dateField.$error)">Click</button>
```

I want to validate errors on click of button in the controller

```
$scope.check=function(errors){


  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angularjs creates a `scope` variable for `form` whenever it is used to check the validation of that form. Now you can directly use `form.$valid` , `formName.$invalid` and many more pre-defined properties in `html` directly. But if you want to use it in the controller just pass it to the controller using `md-button` (while submitting the form).

```
<form name="myForm">
  <md-datepicker name="dateField" ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date" required="" md-min-date="minDate" md-max-date="maxDate" md-date-filter="onlyWeekendsPredicate"></md-datepicker>

  <div class="validation-messages" ng-messages="myForm.dateField.$error">
    <div ng-message="valid">The entered value is not a date!</div>
    <div ng-message="required">This date is required!</div>
    <div ng-message="mindate">Date is too early!</div>
    <div ng-message="maxdate">Date is too late!</div>
    <div ng-message="filtered">Only weekends are allowed!</div>
  </div>
  <md-button ng-click="check(myForm)">check/md-button>
</form>
```

Here is a working example. You can the whole object in console which is printed by controller as desired. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/rLebeK

Answer (score 1):

You already got that right but missing the validation. The correct way is to check the property `$scope.myForm.$valid`, that will be `true` when the form is valid and `false` otherwise. Check the [Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

---

Other way is to check for the empty object (so no errors) but it checks for that input only:

in the HTML:

```
<button ng-click="check(myForm.myName.$error)">Click</button>
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.check = function (val){

 // check if is empty
 var ok = !!(Object.keys(val).length === 0 && val.constructor === Object);

}
```

I don't recommend this approach unless you want to do it yourself or deal with specific errors.

[See this Plunker with both ways](https://plnkr.co/edit/gqOx0J?p=preview)